# How define a style for custom winform control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am using a control that was developed for Winforms in a program based on WPF.
Defined as below :

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1">
                <common:AlertViewer x:Name="alertViewer"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

(not sure if that is the proper way to use such a control but it seems to be working fine. Let me know if you know a better way)

I defined the style in my app.xaml file as below :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type common:AlertViewer}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Microsoft Sans Serif" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8" />
</Style>
```

I tried a couple of things like define a `x:Key="AlertViewerStyle"` tag from style and add `d:Style="{StaticResource AlertViewerStyle}"` in AlertViewer and did not work either.

Got a couple a error message depending on my try:

> Cannot find the Style Property 'FontFamily' on the type

when remove the "d:style" and replace by "style" I got the message:

> The property 'Style' was not found in type 'AlertViewer'.

winform seem to have a property "Font" but not sure how to define it in such case.

Can you please help me figure ?

Thanks

Comment: A WPF Style can only be applied to a WPF control. AlertViewer is not a WPF control.

Comment: Use `<WindowsFormsHost FontSize="8" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif">` or a Style that targets WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried define the style to WindowsFormsHost  (like above) but it did not apply to the control AlertViewer :(

Comment: As Clemens suggested, some properties of WindowsFormsHost including [FontFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.fontfamily) and [FontSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.fontsize) are supposed to set Font of hosted control. I guess you made a mistake in creating the WindowsFormsHost's Style. Show your AlertViewer's code so that it can be tested with the proper Style.

Comment: I can't share the code :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set these properties in Code behind only, because WinForms does not support the concept of DependencyProperty and -Object, which would be a precondition for setting property values in XAML.

However `WindowsFormsHost` exposes the hosted WinForms control nonetheless, through its [WindowsFormsHost.Child Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.child?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property, which is of type `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. With a reference to the control, you should be able to program against it as in WinForms.

XAML-Markup:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1" Name="AlertViewerHost">
                <common:AlertViewer x:Name="alertViewer"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

And in C#, for example in the Window.Loaded event-handler of the code-behind file:

```
var alertViewer = AlertViewerHost.Child as AlertViewer;
// make sure to use the Drawing/WinForms classes that often
// have the same name as the WPF classes.
alertViewer.Font = new System.Drawing.Font ("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8f, 
         System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Note: I didn't test it. I don't know if it renders the expected way.

Comment: I tried this directly using element alertViewer  (like alertViewer.Font...) but it did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

WindowsFormsHost offers the access to some properties of the hosted control including [FontFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.fontfamily) and [FontSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.fontsize) and thus you can set them via WindowsFormsHost's properties. The following is the sample of System.Windows.Forms.Label as the hosted control.

```xml
<Grid xmlns:WinForms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="WindowsFormsHostStyle" TargetType="{x:Type WindowsFormsHost}">
            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="DeepSkyBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <WindowsFormsHost Style="{StaticResource WindowsFormsHostStyle}">
        <WinForms:Label Text="Sample"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

We don't know what is your AlertViewer is but let's say it is a derived class of System.Windows.Forms.UserControl and you placed some Labels in it. If you don't set the Font properties of those Labels, their Fonts will follow the Font of UserControl and thus they can be changed via WindowsFormsHost's properties.

In contrast, if you specifically set Font properties of those Labels, their Fonts won't respect the Font of the UserControl and thus cannot be changed.

Comment: There are some preconditions that need to be satisfied by the Winforms-control implementation in order to make the WPF-styles applicable. Ex-MSDN has an overview: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.fontfamily

Comment: @lidqy Yes, it is exactly what I tried to explain.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're using a third party `AlertViewer` and let's say it exposes properties that control an animated fade in.

```
public class AlertViewer
{
    double AlertOpacity { get; set; }
    double Step { get; set; }
}
```

And the objective might be to apply a `Style` to instances of `AlertViewer` in order to control the font and animation consistently for multiple instances.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:WindowsAlertHost}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Audiowide" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="AlertOpacity" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Step" Value="0.01" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

---

Since the the animation properties obviously aren't available in `WindowsFormsHost`, it's necessary to take matters into our own hands, making a custom `WindowsAlertHost : WindowsFormsHost` that lets you do anything you want in terms of style to an `AlertViewer` that it specifically hosts.

```
public class WindowsAlertHost : WindowsFormsHost
{
    public WindowsAlertHost() => Child = new AlertViewer();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlertOpacityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AlertOpacity",
            typeof(float),
            typeof(WindowsAlertHost),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(float), OnAlertOpacityChanged));
    public float AlertOpacity
    {
        get => (float)GetValue(AlertOpacityProperty);
        set => SetValue(AlertOpacityProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StepProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Step",
            typeof(float),
            typeof(WindowsAlertHost),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(float), OnStepChanged));

    public float Step
    {
        get => (float)GetValue(StepProperty);
        set => SetValue(StepProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnAlertOpacityChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is WindowsAlertHost host && host.Child is AlertViewer viewer)
        {
            viewer.Opacity = (float)e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    private static void OnStepChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is WindowsAlertHost host && host.Child is AlertViewer viewer)
        {
            viewer.Step = (float)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: animation]

```
<Window x:Class="host_winforms_custom_control.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:host_winforms_custom_control"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="500" Height="300" Background="RoyalBlue">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:WindowsAlertHost}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Audiowide" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="AlertOpacity" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Step" Value="0.01" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Background="Azure">
            <local:WindowsAlertHost Margin="10" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

###### ALTERNATIVE

Your question, and my answer, are about how to **define a style** which implies that there are several of the same kind of control in use, and that the look and behavior of all of them should be consistent. I'd be remiss if I didn't mention that setting properties *directly* with text or a `StaticResource` is much simpler.

###### Direct set properties on hosted object

```
<Window x:Class="host_winforms_custom_control.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:host_winforms_custom_control"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="500" Height="300" Background="RoyalBlue">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Background="Azure">
            <WindowsFormsHost 
                x:Name="AlertHost"
                FontFamily="Audiowide"
                FontSize="24"
                Margin="10" >
                <local:AlertViewer
                    x:Name="AlertViewer"
                    Step="0.01"
                    AlertOpacity="1.0"/>
            </WindowsFormsHost>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```